# Count items in array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, object, count

I have an array of cars like this.

```
Array
(
    [2] => Car Object
        (
            [userId] => 3
            [value] => 0
        )
    [58] => Car Object
        (
            [userId] => 2
            [value] => 0
        )
    [64] => Car Object
        (
            [userId] => 2
            [value] => 0
        )

)
```

I loop through an array of users and wish to know how many occurrences each userId is represented in the cars array. The array keys are dynamic numbers. Do I need to loop through the cars array each time I loop though the user array? Seems like a lot of looping and I suspect a better solution is available :)

Thanks in advance

Update:
I actually just came up with a solution that seems to work. Might not be pretty. Comments are appreciated

```
$countArray = array();

foreach($cars as $car) {

    if(!$countArray[$car->userId()]) $countArray[$car->userId()] == 0;

    $countArray[$car->userId()]++;
}
```

print_r($countArray) gives me

```
Array ( [94] => 33 [84] => 15 [88] => 53 [80] => 69 [83] => 14 [93] => 3 [76] => 69 [86] => 51 [82] => 77 [87] => 20 [112] => 12 [115] => 16 [114] => 10 [113] => 2 [77] => 1 )
```

which seems about right

Comment: Can you share what you have tried and the issues that you had with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
array_count_values( array_map(function($v) { return $v->userId; }, $array) );
```

result

```
Array
(
    [3] => 1
    [2] => 2
)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the count in the User object. Every time you add a car, increment the count for the appropriate user. Every time you remove a car, decrement the count. This will be faster, but more error prone - if you forget to increment or decrement the count at some point, your data will be wrong.